# Retrieve more than 10000 rows from refinitiv workspace

Tags: python, refinitiv-eikon-api, refinitiv-eikon

I'm trying to retrieve all the bonds from refinitiv workspace. I want to extract all the 250000+ bonds and actually I don't know how to do this. Here's the code I wrote:

```
import refinitiv.dataplatform as rdp
import refinitiv.dataplatform.eikon as ek

ek.set_app_key('mykey')
ddf = rdp.
df = rdp.search(

    view=rdp.SearchViews.FixedIncomeInstruments,

    filter="IsGreenBond eq false",

    select='Name, DocumentTitle, RIC, ISIN, AssetTypeDescription, MaturityDate, FaceOutstandingUSD, TrancheAmount, CouponClass, Currency, IssueDate, SeniorityTypeDescription, MaturityCorpModDuration, MaturityCorpYield, Price, SectorDescription',
    top=20000,
)

print(df)
```

I find out that there's a method from the refinitiv API that allows to do this, but only for the first (top) 10000.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that there's a [Q&A Forum](https://community.developers.refinitiv.com/index.html) specifically for refinitiv and [LSEG](https://www.lseg.com/en) APIs.

But to answer your question: you'll have to narrow down your search into buckets, say per country, and put it in a loop. The following articles will help you find out how:

- [Find content and functionality using Refinitiv Data Library with Eikon Advanced Search](https://developers.refinitiv.com/en/article-catalog/article/Find-content-and-functionality-using-Refinitiv-Data-Library-with-Eikon-Advanced-Search)
- [Build queries easily using Refinitiv's Search API with Python and Jupyter](https://developers.refinitiv.com/en/article-catalog/article/build-expressions-with-refinitiv-search-python-jupyter-notebook) & its partner [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Refinitiv-API-Samples/Article.DataLibrary.Python.SearchBrowser).
- [Building Search into your Application Workflow](https://developers.refinitiv.com/en/article-catalog/article/building-search-into-your-application-workflow)

With that said, I think that maybe [screener](https://developers.refinitiv.com/en/article-catalog/article/find-your-right-companies-with-screener-eikon-data-apis-python) might be the better tool to use here?

If you need more help, please do not hesitate to ask in the Q&A Forum.

Answer (score 0):

Hi In response to your inquiry, here's a sample code from Refinitiv:

```
df = rdp.Search.search(
    view = rdp.SearchViews.GovCorpInstruments,
    filter = f"ParentOAPermID eq '{org_id}'and IsActive eq true and not(AssetStatus in ('MAT'))",

    # Define the upper limit of rows within our result set.  This is a imposed maximum value.
    top = 10000, 
    select = ','.join(properties),
    navigators = "Currency"
)
```

The maximum amount of data output retrievable from Eikon is capped at 10,000 due to system-imposed limitations. Therefore, setting the parameter top to 20,000 will result in the query failing and yielding an empty data frame.

Please visit the article linked [here](https://developers.lseg.com/en/article-catalog/article/debt-structure-analysis-on-an-organizational-level) to check more details.